# Visual Studio 2022 17.5.2 broken IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

So, my team updated to Version 17.5.2 today.

And IntelliSense is DOWN on all 5+ workstations (C++ projects).

Whenever we attempt to navigate into a function etc. It shows
'navigating to definition' and that's it..

We've tried deleting the '.vs' temporary folder which used to solve stuff when anything unexpected happened, doesn't seem to work this time.

In fact IntelliSense doesn't work ***at all***... no suggestions and there's no 'parsing' progress which used to be shown at the bottom of its windows once a large project was opened..

It doesn't even work for language internal constructs. Nothing.

[image]

anyone? Anything we could possibly try before calling MS or reinstalling VS on multiple workstations?

Possibly related to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185434/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2022-17-5-intellisense-no

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like InteliSense in 17.5 is indeed utterly broken so we've just used the rollback-to-previous-version functionality introduced by Microsoft in 17.4... seemingly just on time, Microsoft...

**All good now.**

As a side note, probably the biggest bummer which happened to us after updating VS in over a decade.

We live in Visual Studio and we consider it some of the best software on our planet but oh well, seems like sh*** happens. Remember receiving brand new box with Visual C++ 6.0 from my dad. Wonderful stuff.